# Why does toggling visibility works only after second click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button that should toggle between visibility `visible` and `hidden`, and even though I specify in CSS that the `div` has `visibility: hidden`, the JS code first sees the CSS as blank (as if I did not specify the style).

Only after the second click (`mouseup` event in my case), it detects the visibility and the toggling starts working, why?

Here's a snippet:

```js
let button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.addEventListener("mouseup", toggleVisibility)

function toggleVisibility() {
  let div = document.getElementById("div");
  if (div.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    div.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    div.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
#div {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button id="button"> toggle </button>

<div id="div">
  <h1> Hello, World! </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: The `.style` property is only accessing inline styles, it doesn't know about anything applied by a style sheet. [MDN HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Comment: <div id="div" style="visibility: hidden;"> add this it will solve the problem issue is that it's applying inline style in inline styling you didn't give visibility any value so first click apply a value and on second click condition work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div.style` reads from the `style` attribute not the actual applied styles. To fix this you can either use inline styling or get the computed style via [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Example inline styling:

---

```js
let button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.addEventListener("mouseup", toggleVisibility)

function toggleVisibility() {
  let div = document.getElementById("div");
  if (div.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    div.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    div.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="button"> toggle </button>

<div id="div" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <h1> Hello, World! </h1>
</div>
```

Example `getComputedStyle()`:

---

```js
let button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.addEventListener("mouseup", toggleVisibility)

function toggleVisibility() {
  let div = document.getElementById("div");
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(div);
  
  if (style.visibility === "hidden") {
    div.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    div.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
#div {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button id="button"> toggle </button>

<div id="div">
  <h1> Hello, World! </h1>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: As pointed out in the comments toggling a class is another alternative. This is especially useful if you need to change more then one style.

---

```js
let button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.addEventListener("mouseup", toggleVisibility)

function toggleVisibility() {
  let div = document.getElementById("div");
  div.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
#div {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#div.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<button id="button"> toggle </button>

<div id="div">
  <h1> Hello, World! </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! Is there a preferable method out of the two? Is any of them considered "better practice"?

Comment: @Stackerito Using proper CSS and `getComputedStyle` is definitely the better practice

Comment: @Stackerito To be honest a better approach would be to add/remove a class from the element, and apply styles to that class. Avoiding inline style manipulation entirely.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate style properties of an element, you need to use the `window.getComputedStyle()` method.

In your case, the code should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#div {
  visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
<body>

<button id="button"> toggle </button>

<div id="div">
  <h1> Hello, World! </h1>
</div>

<script>
let button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.addEventListener("mouseup", toggleVisibility)

function toggleVisibility() {
  let div = document.getElementById("div");
  
  if(window.getComputedStyle(div).visibility === "hidden") {
    div.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    div.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Soi if you don't want to use inline-css;

```js
let button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.addEventListener("mouseup", toggleVisibility)

function toggleVisibility() {
  let div = document.getElementById("div");
  let compStylesStatus = window.getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue('visibility');

  if (compStylesStatus  === "hidden") {
       div.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
       div.style.visibility = "hidden"
  }
}
```

```css
#div {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button id="button"> toggle </button>

<div id="div">
  <h1> Hello, World! </h1>
</div>
```